Color is not matching after applying URP post processing in Unity
I am trying to replicate google model viewer rendering look and feel in Unity 2022.3.22.
I am using URP sample demo project with high configurations.
I have added the same HDRI setup in my Unity scene.
To match the rendering view with google model viewer

I am applying post-processing, but with it actual color of the model is changing.
even when I am using Unlit textures then also due to post processing it’s changing.

Here you can find the detailed comparison doc among unity viewer(on left) and Model viewer(on right) for better understanding.Also attached here few for quick references.
Sample 1 imported FBX in unity
Sample 1 tweaked materials as per model viewer material properties
Sample 2, looks almost similar
global volume
in Color adjustments: contrast, saturation, post exposure.
in Color Curves: Master curve, red hue curve.
also tried comparing both modes tone-mapping mode, and both has slight differences in color mainly.
Tried comparing tone-mappers
Unity Viewer Neutral VS Godel Viewer Neutral
Unity Viewer ACES VS Google viewer ACES
Lighting settings
Environmental lights, Neutral HDRI and reflections with realtime GI.
HDRI’s exposure and angle mapped exactly. color difference exist there also.
Maybe I should not use post processing, but then model looks very off-color/grey/bright etc.
And with Post-processing mainly color is getting messy.
HDRI Texture settings
Environment lighting settings
Scene lighting settings
Global volume settings
Now,

Should I use some other configuration rather then post-processing?
Or maybe some way to fix the color difference via altering the post-processing stack itself?

Any help or clue would be really appreciative related to this.
Thank in advance!

I dont see different colours, I see a different amount of light, and its barely noticable at that

Lighting is applied in same way for all models. Actually it's tint difference mainly and it's intensity varies b/w different type of models. Mainly it's washing out the colors.

Have you tried changing the Color Space of your project?
It is at Project Setting - Player - Other Settings - Rendering
Generally for 3d models, Gamma shows the same color as Blender.
If this is not the problem, try to set the Volume layer so that the unlit objects surely don't get any post-processing effect.

We tried with Gamma color space, but it doesn't work well for all models with Neutral tone-mapper. Layer Idea for unlit textures can be helpful, will try to implemente for my use-case.

Every program has it's own different rendering method. To achieve exellance in their unique field, you can't promise the exact same output from different program. the only solution is to tweak the pipeline and the shaders just like how you did. Bon courage.
